# Drupal7 Contextual filters with clean URLS

Tags: drupal-7, view

i have a little problem to work in my webpages with clean URL's + Views

I have a web page with some views. One of the views get four parameters.

Contextual_Filter > Provide Default Value > Raw Value from URL > PathComponent > 3

Then my filter works with something similar like this -> 551/550/73/2012-08-11

When translate this in my web page, apear something like this. www.mydomain.com/node/551/550/73/2012-08-11

This Id correspond a content for example.

www.mydomain.com/node/julio-iglesias/Barcelona/My_song/2012-08-11

But i cant translate into the correct URL...

Someone know a way to do this.

Thx !!!